# Underscore destroy method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

for code below after checking checkbox on particular answer the answer will be deleted after submitting form.

Can somwone please explain if this destroy method needs to be defined anywhere or is that a default? I cannot find any documentation. Actually how this functionality works?

The source is from here:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?autoplay=true

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :content, "Answer" %>
  <%= f.text_field :content %>
  <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
  <%= f.label :_destroy, "Remove" %>
</p>
```

Comment: It’s from [`ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) which _"will allow you to also use the `_destroy` key to destroy existing records"_. You just have to provide that key and Rails will handle the destruction. (for those with `allow_destroy: true`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

For this, to work we define `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on the parent model which does all the magic.

**Long Answer:** (How `accepts_nested_attributes_for` does this magic?)

This is the source code:

```
def accepts_nested_attributes_for(*attr_names)
  options = { allow_destroy: false, update_only: false }
  options.update(attr_names.extract_options!)
  options.assert_valid_keys(:allow_destroy, :reject_if, :limit, :update_only)
  options[:reject_if] = REJECT_ALL_BLANK_PROC if options[:reject_if] == :all_blank
  attr_names.each do |association_name|
    if reflection = _reflect_on_association(association_name)
      reflection.autosave = true
      define_autosave_validation_callbacks(reflection)

      nested_attributes_options = self.nested_attributes_options.dup
      nested_attributes_options[association_name.to_sym] = options
      self.nested_attributes_options = nested_attributes_options

      type = (reflection.collection? ? :collection : :one_to_one)
      generate_association_writer(association_name, type)
    else
      raise ArgumentError, "No association found for name `#{association_name}'. Has it been defined yet?"
    end
  end
end
```

Here you can see it calls `generate_association_writer(association_name, type)` which defines the setter method like this:

```
def generate_association_writer(association_name, type)
  generated_association_methods.module_eval <<-eoruby, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
    silence_redefinition_of_method :#{association_name}_attributes=
    def #{association_name}_attributes=(attributes)
      assign_nested_attributes_for_#{type}_association(:#{association_name}, attributes)
    end
  eoruby
end
```

Suppose you have this class:

```
class BlogPost < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Then this will generate: `comments_attributes=` setter method dynamically on the model. Now from the view when you add a block:

```
<% f.fields_for :comments do |comment| %>
<% end %>
```

It passes the values in the `comments_attributes` key (if you check the `params` on the controller you will find that also you have to whitelist this attribute on strong params to make it work). So this automatically calls the generated setter method.

Now based on the type of association (single or collection) it calls `assign_nested_attributes_for_one_to_one_association` or `assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association` method which calls `assign_to_or_mark_for_destruction` which marks the object for destruction if `_destroy` is `true` if you have allowed to destroy and it is an existing object.

**For reference:**

```
def assign_nested_attributes_for_one_to_one_association(association_name, attributes)
  options = nested_attributes_options[association_name]
  if attributes.respond_to?(:permitted?)
    attributes = attributes.to_h
  end
  attributes = attributes.with_indifferent_access
  existing_record = send(association_name)

  if (options[:update_only] || !attributes["id"].blank?) && existing_record &&
      (options[:update_only] || existing_record.id.to_s == attributes["id"].to_s)
    assign_to_or_mark_for_destruction(existing_record, attributes, options[:allow_destroy]) unless call_reject_if(association_name, attributes)

  elsif attributes["id"].present?
    raise_nested_attributes_record_not_found!(association_name, attributes["id"])

  elsif !reject_new_record?(association_name, attributes)
    assignable_attributes = attributes.except(*UNASSIGNABLE_KEYS)

    if existing_record && existing_record.new_record?
      existing_record.assign_attributes(assignable_attributes)
      association(association_name).initialize_attributes(existing_record)
    else
      method = :"build_#{association_name}"
      if respond_to?(method)
        send(method, assignable_attributes)
      else
        raise ArgumentError, "Cannot build association `#{association_name}'. Are you trying to build a polymorphic one-to-one association?"
      end
    end
  end
end

def assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association(association_name, attributes_collection)
  options = nested_attributes_options[association_name]
  if attributes_collection.respond_to?(:permitted?)
    attributes_collection = attributes_collection.to_h
  end

  unless attributes_collection.is_a?(Hash) || attributes_collection.is_a?(Array)
    raise ArgumentError, "Hash or Array expected for attribute `#{association_name}`, got #{attributes_collection.class.name} (#{attributes_collection.inspect})"
  end

  check_record_limit!(options[:limit], attributes_collection)

  if attributes_collection.is_a? Hash
    keys = attributes_collection.keys
    attributes_collection = if keys.include?("id") || keys.include?(:id)
      [attributes_collection]
    else
      attributes_collection.values
    end
  end

  association = association(association_name)

  existing_records = if association.loaded?
    association.target
  else
    attribute_ids = attributes_collection.filter_map { |a| a["id"] || a[:id] }
    attribute_ids.empty? ? [] : association.scope.where(association.klass.primary_key => attribute_ids)
  end

  attributes_collection.each do |attributes|
    if attributes.respond_to?(:permitted?)
      attributes = attributes.to_h
    end
    attributes = attributes.with_indifferent_access

    if attributes["id"].blank?
      unless reject_new_record?(association_name, attributes)
        association.reader.build(attributes.except(*UNASSIGNABLE_KEYS))
      end
    elsif existing_record = existing_records.detect { |record| record.id.to_s == attributes["id"].to_s }
      unless call_reject_if(association_name, attributes)
        # Make sure we are operating on the actual object which is in the association's
        # proxy_target array (either by finding it, or adding it if not found)
        # Take into account that the proxy_target may have changed due to callbacks
        target_record = association.target.detect { |record| record.id.to_s == attributes["id"].to_s }
        if target_record
          existing_record = target_record
        else
          association.add_to_target(existing_record, skip_callbacks: true)
        end

        assign_to_or_mark_for_destruction(existing_record, attributes, options[:allow_destroy])
      end
    else
      raise_nested_attributes_record_not_found!(association_name, attributes["id"])
    end
  end
end

def assign_to_or_mark_for_destruction(record, attributes, allow_destroy)
  record.assign_attributes(attributes.except(*UNASSIGNABLE_KEYS))
  record.mark_for_destruction if has_destroy_flag?(attributes) && allow_destroy
end

def has_destroy_flag?(hash)
  Type::Boolean.new.cast(hash["_destroy"])
end
```

You would find all the code in `activerecord/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb` class: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb

Answer (score 1):

The `_destroy` 'attribute' functionality is part of working with nested forms/attributes.

Suppose you have a `Quiz` model that `has_many :answers`. To be able to update a Quiz and its child `Answer` objects in one operation, you declare that with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`:

```rb
class Quiz < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end
```

If your form uses the `<% f.fields_for :answers %>` construct (shown in your video), Rails will organize the parameter hash so that you can update the parent quiz and it will also automatically create/update any child answers. By default, though, you can only update an existing child or create new ones. If you want to also be able to delete nested objects, you need first to explicitly enable it in the model:

```rb
class Quiz < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Then, per the [API docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) for `NestedAttributes`:

> when you add the `_destroy` key to the attributes hash, with a value
> that evaluates to true, you will destroy the associated model.

So, as long as you have enabled nested destruction on the model, adding a `f.check_box :_destroy` field to your nested form, Rails will automagically remove the marked record.